# Php Iterator foreach on object properties

Tags: php, class, oop, object, abstract

Given a class

```
class Obj {
 public $a =1;
 public $b = 2;
}
```

and script like

```
$obj = new Obj();

foreach($obj as $key => $value)
    echo $key, $value;
```

I can easily output what's inside the object, but why doesn't it work if the class is like that

```
class SomeClass() implements Iterator {
...
}
```

Is Iterator interface forbidden me to do foreach outside and forcing me to use its abstract functions for this purpose? Tyvm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When a class implements `Iterator`, `foreach` iterates over the elements of the collection that it represents. When the class doesn't implement `Iterator`, it falls back to iterating over the properties.

If you want to iterate over the properties of this class, convert the object to an array:

```
foreach ((array)$obj as $key => $value)
    echo $key, $value;
```

Comment: I got that, my question was that after implementing that interface I can't use foreach() over the object like before, is that due to the implementation? Does it forbids it?

Comment: You can't have it both ways. Since it iterates over the collection, it can't also iterate over the properties.